# MS Excel 2013 - Too Many Arguments

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Getting an error when trying to combine five total arguments.

I am trying to use an error checking argument.  Previously, I was able to accomplish this with only three arguments:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A19,2))),IF(AND(S19="HOME",O19=""),"Pass",IF(AND(S19="DET",O19="X"),"Pass",IF(AND(H19="OOR",O19=""),"Pass","Fail"))),"")
```

I want to expand this to include two new parameters, similar to this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A19,2))),IF(AND(S19="HOME",O19=""),"Pass",IF(AND(S19="HOME",O19=""),"Pass",IF(AND(S19="DET",O19="X"),"Pass",IF(AND(S19="OTHER",O19="X"),"Pass",IF(AND(H19="OOR",O19=""),"Pass","Fail"))),"")
```

When I try this, I receive:

> "You've entered too many arguments for this function."

Answer (score 1):

Excel gives you a hint after the "too many arguments" message.  It highlights the final "" in your formula.  It thinks the error is near that position.

The problem is that you're missing some parentheses.  Near the end of your formula, between the word "Fail" and the next comma, there needs to be a total of 5 close parens.

You can troubleshoot these kinds of issues by clicking in the formula bar, clicking in a portion of the formula, and then clicking on one of the parameters that Excel shows in the popup.

In the picture below, I clicked on the first AND(), and then clicked on **logical_test** in the popup.  Excel responded by highlighting the logical test for this IF() function.

If you click on the very first IF() in your formula, you'll notice that you can't click on **value_if_false** because Excel thinks you haven't entered it yet.  If you click **value_if_true**, Excel highlights all the rest of the formula.

[image]

After you add the missing parens, it will highlight only up to the last comma, and it will be able to find the value_if_false.

Comment: That was perfect!  Thank you so much for the help and explanation!

Comment: Glad to help, good luck.